# How do I Regex match an Underscore at end of string?

Tags: c#, regex

I have following pattern which fails with the underscore at the end but works otherwise

".\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}_."

EDIT:

so I want all string that look with this:

ANY TEXT HERE **10.20_** ANY TEXT HERE

"Here is a sample 10.20_ that i use."

"10.20_ is another sample."

Comment: Try adding ^ to the regex pattern after underscore. Unless your line ends with a dot. Then you would have to escape dot with \.
So your pattern would look something like "_\.^" this

Comment: @Dimitri: I think you mean `$` -- `^` is beginning of line.

Comment: Please add three things. 1. RegEx, 2. Sample Input, 3. Expected output.

Comment: $ is, but ^ is end. $-----^ means one line from begining to end.

Comment: So you want to get a match when an underscore is at the end of the string? Why not simply do `myString.EndsWith("_")`?

Comment: @Dimitri: Unless I'm just misundestanding your point, you're wrong. You're getting `$` and `^` anchors mixed up. See for example http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-2

Comment: @ean5533 - $ denotes start of line, where as ^ denotes its end... When used together in a single pattern they will match entire single line. I have used $ and ^ separately to match expression to either just in the beginning or end of line

Comment: @Dimitri: This is the last time I'm going to say this: **You've got them backwards**. `$` denotes the END OF LINE, while `^` denotes the START OF LINE. Click on the link I added in my last comment, or do a google search, or do anything, but don't spread incorrect information.

Comment: yeah, that's what i meant. got them backwards and misunderstood your reply...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After the `_` there is a `.` which means one occurrence of a character except line break. So if the `_` is at end it will not match the regex. You have not given any examples of what you want, and just the regex, but you may want to make it `.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}_.?`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
^.*\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}_.*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the period in the regex pattern is confusing. It says give me any character, do you want the white space before and possibly after? If so specify as \s? for both the beginning or the end. If you just want the number simply use:

```
\d\d?\.\d\d?_
```

Or am I missing something?